# How to run the HTTP request without using CURL

Tags: curl, busybox

I have arm-based busybox (Embedded Linux) with limited binaries. How to http post or put without using curl?

Comment: Check if you have `wget` it offers some similar features, but actually, you should  tell us more about your project specification..PLEASE eidt your question and don't reply in comments. Also, this is likely to get closed, as it's not about solving an 'if/then/else/endif' type coding problem. The related sites here on stackExchange , http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com OR http://unix.stackexchange.com may be better places to ask this Q. Good luck!

Answer (score 22):

`busybox` has `wget` but this limited and unsuitable for posting.
You can combine `busybox` with `netcat` (or `nc`) for achieving the result. You only need to download `netcat` binaries for your platform. And here we go:

```
POST_PATH="/login.cgi"
HOST=199.188.1.99
BODY="Put here HTML body...."
BODY_LEN=$( echo -n "${BODY}" | wc -c )
echo -ne "POST ${POST_PATH} HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: ${HOST}\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nContent-Length: ${BODY_LEN}\r\n\r\n${BODY}" | \
  nc -i 3 ${HOST} 80
```

Based on [Sending HTTP POST request with netcat](http://www.egeek.me/2014/08/17/sending-http-post-request-with-netcat/) post.

Comment: Update for 2022: Busybox now also has a netcat applet https://github.com/mirror/busybox/blob/master/networking/nc.c

Comment: Update for 2023: See Sandip answer. Much easier starting with Busybox 1.35.0

Comment: Also update for 2023: May still need this for PUT, as the BusyBox 1.35.0 wget still only supports POST

Comment: But does busybox nc solution have a way to connect over SSL to an HTTPS host?

Comment: @ms-ati, **`nc`** can connect to server via **TCP**, but **can't** negotiate **SSL/TLS** connection. You should use **`curl`/`wget`** to work with **HTTPS**. Or more _raw_-variant is to use **OpenSSL**'s `s_clent` instead **`nc`**, for example: `echo -ne "GET /not_exist HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n" | openssl s_client -quiet google.com:443`

Answer (score 5):

i just have the same problem as you so i decided to create minimum image from alpine that do lot more than busy box and less than ubuntu
https://hub.docker.com/r/prima101112/palugada

you could do curl traceroute or even vim to edit inside pods or container

or if you want to still go with busybox usually i will go

```
kubectl exec -it busybox -- wget {url}
kubectl exec -it busybox -- cat index.html
```

that command will show the response

hope this will help

Comment: This can be a great comment but not an answer. Please read the rules.

Comment: yeah sorry my bad. i have edited the comment. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use `wget --post-data "xxx" -q $URL` to make a POST request to URL with `xxx` as the post data.

Comment: This should be the accepted starting with Busybox 1.35.0